# django-tables2 linkcolumn multiple items in the same cell

Tags: django, django-tables2

I'd like to add multiple 'items' to the same cell using `tables.LinkColumn`.

Something like this:

```
column_name = tables.LinkColumn('some_url_edit', args=[A('pk')], attrs={'class':'tbl_icon edit'})
column_name += tables.LinkColumn('some_url_del', args=[A('pk')], attrs={'class':'tbl_icon delete'})
column_name += ...
```

Is this even possible? or should I create my own table view, without `django-tables`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have two options here, either use a [`TemplateColumn`](http://django-tables.readthedocs.org/en/latest/?redir#templatecolumn-objects), or write a [`render_FOO`](http://django-tables.readthedocs.org/en/latest/?redir#table-render-foo-methods) method.

Here is an example using the `TemplateColumn` (as you can see the record is added to the context that is used to render the template, thus allowing you to access the `pk` via `record.pk`:

```
TEMPLATE = '''
   <a href="{% url some_url_edit record.pk %}" class="tbl_icon edit">Edit</a>
   <a href="{% url some_url_del record.pk %}" class="tbl_icon delete">Delete</a>
'''

class MyTable(tables.Table):
    column_name = tables.TemplateColumn(TEMPLATE)
```

Example using the `render_FOO`:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class MyTable(tables.Table):
    column_name = tables.Column()

    def render_column_name(self, record):
        edit_url = reverse("some_url_edit", args=[record.pk])
        del_url = reverse("some_url_del", args=[record.pk])
        return mark_safe('''<a href="%s" class="tbl_icon edit">Edit</a>
                         <a href="%s" class="tbl_icon delete">Delete</a>'''
                         % (edit_url, del_url))
```

As you can see the `TemplateColumn` approach is probably a little cleaner in
your case.

Comment: I didn't make the `TemplateColumn` stuff very obvious, it's only covered in the API Reference at the very bottom.

Answer (score -1):

Example with render foo didn't work for me with column defined as `tables.Column()`.
Now i use TemplateColumn with render_FOO.

```
TEMPLATE = "<text></text>"
column_name = tables.TemplateColumn(TEMPLATE)
```