# Django_table2 TemplateColumn usage

Tags: django-tables2

I just read the [folowing article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275193/django-tables2-linkcolumn-multiple-items-in-the-same-cell) and i would like more information about the first method using TemplateColumn. I would like to produce two pseudo columns for edit and delete methods of each record.

edit.html

```
> <a href="{% url some_url_edit record.pk %}" class="tbl_icon
> edit">Edit</a>
```

delete.html

```
> <a href="{% url some_url_del record.pk %}" class="tbl_icon
> delete">Delete</a>
```

## 2 pseudo columns that does not exist in DB

> class MyTable(tables.Table):
>       column_edit = tables.TemplateColumn(edit.html)
>       column_delete=tables.TemplateColumn(delete.html)

If that is correct according to the article how record.pk is passed on every template to get the required information about its key?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit or delete an object then you'd need to use a model table:

```
class MyModelTable(tables.Table):
    name = tables.columns.Column()
    edit = tables.TemplateColumn('<a href='{% url "edit_my_model_instance" record.id %}'>Edit</a>', verbose_name=u'Edit', )    
    delete = tables.TemplateColumn('<a href='{% url "del_my_model_instance" record.id %}'>Delete</a>', verbose_name=u'Delete', )    

    class Meta:
        model = models.MyModel
```

Notice how we use `record.id` to pass it the id of each row to the `url` template tag in order to output the correct edit/delete url.

Comment: In case we want to display link images instead of link text with verbose_name how this happens? Should we place somewhere a class and how we define it above in this code?

Comment: Using the TemplateColumn you can display whatever you want. For example, if instead of the Edit text you want to display an image you can just use `edit = tables.TemplateColumn('<a href='{% url "edit_my_model_instance" record.id %}'><img src=\'{% static "edit_image.png" %}\' /></a>', verbose_name=u'Edit', )`

Answer (score 0):

i am afraid that your code is a bit faulty as someone must use the following commands to get properly displayed the images inside the columns: 
                                                                                                  `edit = tables.TemplateColumn('<a href="{% url "edit_division" record.pk %}"><img src=\'{% load  staticfiles %} {% static "images/edit.jpg" %}\' / width="25"></a>',verbose_name=u'Edit',)`

```
 delete = tables.TemplateColumn('<a href="{% url "delete_division" record.pk %}"><img src=\'{% load  staticfiles %} {% static "images/delete.jpg" %}\' / width="25"></a>',verbose_name=u'Delete',)
```

I would like to ask if i could use inside tables.py bootstrap css for better rendering of columns and data tables?

Comment: Yes you can - I think you should add a `class='table'` to your table's `Meta`.

Comment: I have used successfully in my tables.py the following command attrs = {"class":"paleblue"}, but i want to use two classes similar to attrs = {"class":["paleblue","table-responsive"]} for mobile friendly but it does not work ??? thanks

Comment: I think that paleblue is different than the bootstrap classes - I recommend using only the "table table-responsive" classes.

Comment: I tried to use attrs = {"class":"table"} in tables.py and i got nothing on rendering. Should i include a css as header in the template and which file. Besides is there a command where i can use many classes together similar to attrs = {"class":["paleblue","table table-responsive"]}. I think paleblue is only a theme class included default inside djnago-tables2. Thanks

Comment: Yes, paleblue is the default theme of djagno-tables2, but I think that if you have included the bootstrap.css you'll get the bootstrap styling by adding the class "table". Also, from what I see, django-tables2 provides a special template for bootstrap, check the example here: https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2/blob/214b83dd329a60c607db06a7f15b17ebd64e1de4/example/app/tables.py