# Multiple link in cell with LinkColumn - Django-table2

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-tables2

I have a different case than this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275193/django-tables2-linkcolumn-multiple-items-in-the-same-cell).

In this case the number of links is defined.

In my case I generate the link cell with a list of values.

## apps.py

```
for subject in list_of_subject:
    study_name_list = subject["study_name_list"]
    data_studies.append({
        'subject': subject
        'study_name': ", ".join(study_name_list),
    })

table_studies = StudiesTable(data=data_studies)
```

## tables.py

```
class StudiesTable(tables.Table):
    """
    StudiesTable class
    """
    study_name = tables.LinkColumn('study_wiki', args=[A('study_name')], verbose_name='Study')
    subject = tables.Column(verbose_name='Subject')
    class Meta:
        """
        Meta class
        """
        attrs = {'class': 'table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed'}
```

## Now

I can make a link just for the joined string.

## For example:

```
Subject1     |     Study1, Study2          |
Subject2     |     Study3                  |
Subject3     |     Study1, Study2, Study3  |
```

I want that you can click on Study1 and go the page for Study1 and you can click on Study2 and go the page for Study2.

Answer (score 0):

The following method solves my problem in my `StudiesTable` class.

```
def render_study_name(self, value):
    html_string = ""
    value_list = value.split(", ")
    for val in value_list:
        url_value = reverse("study_wiki", args=[A(val)])
        html_string += '''<a href="{0}" >{1}</a><br>'''.format(url_value, val)
    return mark_safe(html_string)
```